# It is possible to create a automatic Folder structure in SFTP from SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a scenario where we don't have to create a folder structure in SFTP manually as we are getting data day to day, and is automatically stored in a monthly folder and so on for every month. We are using FileZilla as our SFTP

Comment: Can you update your question with more specifics? Are you looking for a way to automatically create folders in SFMC SFTP? Why is it needed? If this is for ongoing file imports, I don't think this will be a good idea, as you would need to create each of them as a file location in SFMC Setup as well.

Comment: Hello @LukasLunow, Our client sends us a file on a daily basis and has requested that we keep them informed about which day we receive each file in SFTP. Therefore, we are exploring the possibility of creating a folder structure in SFTP to better organize the files.

Comment: Normal procedure here would be to utilise a naming convention for these files reflecting the date, and use substitution strings to pick up the file from today. Files stored on the Marketing Cloud Enhanced FTP or Safehouse are retained for 21 days and then deleted, so you will not be able to hold a full history of old files - even in custom subfolders.

Comment: "Thank you, @LukasLunow. Your information has cleared up so many doubts."

but it is possible to create this type of scenario, can you help me with how to do it?